# How to exchange lines in the same file?

Tags: bash

I have a text like this (in rows):

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

and I'd like to change line B by line D, and line C to by line E, obtaining (in rows):

```
A
D
E
B
C
F
```

is it any simple way to do it with bash?

Comment: so you know in your input file there are line `B D` and `C E`? you want to exchange them in order?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `mapfile` builtin to read the entire file into an array of lines. Then in that array reorder however you want and write the array back out to a file.